# External Display HDMI out not working

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I know this may be a stupid question but are Samsung monitors supported in Ubuntu? 
I ask because I've recently switched over from windows to Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. I have a Samsung monitor I user as a External display. The Problem is it doesn’t detect any output from my laptop, I check the display settings and it has detected my external display and says it's on.
Can anyone help me with this? This is having a big affect on my workload so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, Samsung monitors are supported. Is the cable ok? If you have the nvidia drivers installed, try with nvidia settings.